# Fitting a curve to data: inconsistent results

Tags: python, optimization, curve-fitting, statsmodels, lmfit

I have a dataset of **nutrient budgets for a set of lakes**. Values are compiled from the literature and I've made the data available online.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from lmfit import Model

data_url = r"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JamesSample/029f59471818929ef9fb87bde95169bc/raw/c5b66b554b9ff9d3c448a80c0b4104f410ab5185/lake_n_budgets.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)
df.head()
```

| Lin | Lout | tau |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 75.0 | 60.0 | 0.1 |
| 365.0 | 262.8 | 0.01 |
| 222.0 | 204.24 | 0.02 |
| 215.0 | 204.25 | 0.01 |
| 18.0 | 17.1 | 2.6 |

`Lin` is the flux of nutrients into the lake (tonnes/year); `Lout` is the flux from the outflow (tonnes/year); and `tau` is the water "residence time" (in years) i.e. the average time water spends circulating in the lake.

According to simple theory, these variables can be related as

[image]

where `sigma` and `n` are empirical constants that I'd like to find.

### Attempt 1

I had a go at fitting this using lmfit

```py
def load_out(Lin, tau, sigma=1, n=1):
    return Lin / (1 + (sigma * (tau**n)))


model = Model(load_out, independent_vars=["Lin", "tau"])
fit = model.fit(df["Lout"], Lin=df["Lin"], tau=df["tau"])
fit
```

which gives the following results

| name | value | standard error | relative error | initial value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sigma | 0.38247010 | 0.06846248 | (17.90%) | 1 |
| n | 0.16005700 | 0.04742237 | (29.63%) | 1 |

So far, so good.

However, in the literature it's common to think in terms of the "transmission factor" of the lakes, which is defined as

[image]

Combining this with the first equation gives

[image]

### Attempt 2

As a "sense check" while learning to use lmfit, I had a go at fitting this version too

```py
def transmission(tau, sigma=1, n=1):
    return 1 / (1 + (sigma * (tau**n)))


df["trans"] = df["Lout"] / df["Lin"]
model = Model(transmission, independent_vars=["tau"])
fit = model.fit(df["trans"], tau=df["tau"])
fit
```

| name | value | standard error | relative error | initial value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sigma | 0.79876962 | 0.05283173 | (6.61%) | 1 |
| n | 0.31295722 | 0.03947685 | (12.61%) | 1 |

**The results are quite different**: the best estimates for `sigma` and `n` are roughly twice what they were before, and the differences are larger than the uncertainty estimates on the parameters. Since this is essentially the same equation - with the same `sigma` and `n` - I'm a bit surprised by this.

### Attempt 3

As a further check, I tried rearranging the equation, taking logs and then fitting a linear regression using statsmodels

[image]

```py
df["y"] = (df["Lin"] / df["Lout"]) - 1
mod = smf.ols(formula='np.log10(y) ~ np.log10(tau)', data=df)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
print()
print("Estimate for sigma:", 10**res.params[0])
print("Estimate for n:", res.params[1])
```

This gives

```
Estimate for sigma: 0.757
Estimate for n: 0.361
```

which is broadly compatible with the results from lmfit in Attempt 2.

### My question(s)

I'd like to understand why attempt 1 gives such different results, and the implications for my analysis.

- **Am I missing something really obvious, or is it reasonable to be surprised by these differences?**
- **Should the uncertainty estimates on the parameters not be larger than the differences between simple rearrangements of the fitted equation?**

If I create a synthetic dataset where the relationship matches exactly, all three approaches give identical results, so I think my code is working correctly. I therefore think the differences are due to characteristics/uncertainties in my dataset, but I'm still puzzled over why the difference is so large.

- **Is there a bug in my lmfit code for attempt 1?**
- **Is attempt 1 fundamentally wrong in some way?**

For attempt 1, I suppose I'm fitting a surface to a set of points in three dimensions, whereas in the other versions I'm fitting a curve in two dimensions. The latter is presumably easier/more robust with a small dataset like this (~170 data points), so I think attempts 2 and 3 probably give the "best" answer.

- **Does the fact that attempt 1 is so different imply this model is just not appropriate for my dataset?**

Thank you! :-)

Comment: This could be an optimization problem, e.g. getting stuck in a local (near) optimum. Try attempt 1 with starting values from attempt 2.

Comment: Thanks @Josef! I have tried that (I should have mentioned it in my post) and the optimizer converges back on the values given above for attempt 1, so I don’t think it’s a local minimum.

Comment: Then I guess it's a difference between additive and multiplicative residual term and changes in the residual variance (heteroscedasticity) implied by the different models.

Comment: I think your point about **heteroscedasticity** is what I was missing, @Josef, and I didn't understand properly until I read the answer from @M Newville, below. If I rearrange Attempt 2 back into Attempt 1 (by multiplying by `Lin`), I have a heteroscedastic error term where the uncertainty is larger for lakes with larger `Lin`. To fit an equivalent model in the form of Attempt 1, I therefore need to provide `weights` for lmfit: `model.fit(df["Lout"], Lin=df["Lin"], tau=df["tau"], weights=1/df['Lin'])`. This gives identical results to Attempt 2.

Comment: Alternatively, I can fit Attempt 2 as `model.fit(df["trans"], tau=df["tau"], weights=df["Lin"])`, which matches my initial results from Attempt 1. However, this implies lakes with larger inputs have lower uncertainty, which is not likely, so Attempt 2 is probably better. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, @Josef, I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is really an answer, or an answer you want to hear, but it is too long to fit into a comment.

I think there is not really a bug in your code, but the fits are not very good. That may be because the model is not appropriate for your data.  Or it may be because your data (or, some of your data) is actually very noisy.

One standard recommendation is to visualize (ie, plot) your data and the initial and/or best-fit model, as this can often reveal where things may be going wrong.   If we take your second formulation and do

```
df["trans"] = df["Lout"] / df["Lin"]

def transmission(tau, sigma=1, n=1):
    return 1 / (1 + (sigma * (tau**n)))


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df["tau"], df["trans"], 'bo', label="data")
plt.plot(df["tau"], transmission(df["tau"], sigma=1, n=1), 'ro',
         label="transmisson(sigma=1, n=1)")
plt.plot(df["tau"], transmission(df["tau"], sigma=0.3, n=0.2), 'r+',
        label="transmisson(sigma=0.3, n=0.2)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

it looks like this:

[image]

And, well, maybe one of those is better that the other, but almost all the data is below `tau=10`, so it is kind of hard to tell for sure. Showing that with

```
 plt.xscale("log")
```

will give:

[image]

and that is just a lot less clear which of those is the better fit.

It may very well be that some of those data are more certain or should have a higher weight (as Josef hinted at in the comments).  As it is, all data points for your `df["trans"]` are assumed to have equal uncertainty during the fit. It sure looks like there is a very wide range of "trans" values for "tau" in the range between 0.1 and 10.  It is very hard to say that the fit is good or indeed even that the data follows the model well at all. I have not looked at whether "Lout" or "Lin" data both have high variability as a function of "tau"...

Comment: Good advice - thanks! I think you're right that this model may not be suitable for my dataset. There are some alternatives I can try, plus maybe a bit more searching to expand/improve the dataset. When I first saw the standard errors for "attempt 1", I thought (perhaps naively), "Hmm, not good, but not terrible either". I only discovered the problem "by accident", when I tried fitting the other models. I guess I need to improve my workflow for evaluating non-linear model fits (e.g. with lmfit).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem!  A couple observations...

I don't think your first model is comparable to the others.  In attempt #1 you are treating `Lout` as a dependent variable and using the model to find values for the predictors tau and sigma that give the *best fit* for `Lout`.  That is different than using the data to predict the *best fit* for `F`, which treats `Lout` **and** `Lin` as dependent.

I like your 3rd attempt.  The problem can clearly be made linear by the transformation you suggest.

There are a couple issues there:

1. As suggested in the other answer, you likely do not have enough data to support the assertion that your estimates of sigma and n are valid for "large tau".  You could plot the residuals for a gut check, but it seems like a stretch.
2. (Perhaps this part is obvious...):  The resultant model has a great F-statistic (there is a relationship to the independent variables sigma and n, **but** the R-Squared value is pretty miserable, meaning there is very little "explanatory power" in those variables and there is either (a) a lot of noise in the data/natural system you are looking at or (b) there are some missing predictors, perhaps such as climate (maybe lakes in warm climates blossom nutrients?), lake depth, fish population... who knows... I'm not a lake expert!  :)

Here's my plot of the (untrimmed for high-tau) data and the model results for your #3 model.  I'd buy it.  I didn't plot the fit, but that could be done.  The relationship appears linear, (w/ lots of noise).  Next steps would be to inspect the residuals and look for normal distribution, but I think that will be fine.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#from lmfit import Model

data_url = r"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JamesSample/029f59471818929ef9fb87bde95169bc/raw/c5b66b554b9ff9d3c448a80c0b4104f410ab5185/lake_n_budgets.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)

print(df.describe())

# let's exclude the "large tau" for now... not enough data
#df = df[df['tau'] <= 15]
df['y'] = np.log10(df['Lin']/df['Lout'] - 1)
df['ln_tau'] = np.log10(df['tau'])

plt.scatter(df['ln_tau'], df['y'])
plt.show()
mod = smf.ols(formula='y~ln_tau', data=df)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
print(f'sigma estimate: {10**res.params[0]} ')
```

#### Outputs

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.323
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.319
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     79.18
Date:                Sun, 25 Sep 2022   Prob (F-statistic):           9.39e-16
Time:                        10:07:45   Log-Likelihood:                -94.525
No. Observations:                 168   AIC:                             193.0
Df Residuals:                     166   BIC:                             199.3
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -0.1210      0.036     -3.384      0.001      -0.192      -0.050
ln_tau         0.3608      0.041      8.899      0.000       0.281       0.441
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.698   Durbin-Watson:                   1.632
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.259   Jarque-Bera (JB):                2.416
Skew:                          -0.291   Prob(JB):                        0.299
Kurtosis:                       3.077   Cond. No.                         1.53
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
sigma estimate: 0.7568943930610125
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I agree the log-log regression is OK-ish. (Also, what constitutes a "good" R2 varies a lot between disciplines: 30% is not actually _that_ bad by the standards of ecology/environmental science ;-) There are some alternative models with additional variables that I can try, but I'll probably need to compile a bigger dataset to constrain the extra model flexibility.